# How do I force declared parameters to require explicit naming?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a hard time thinking this through.  if I wanted all declared parameters to require explicit naming when they're set and I wanted to pick up anything unnamed from the $args variable, how would I do it?

If my script declared the following parameters:

```
param($installdir, $compilemode, $whatever)
```

then passing a list of files (in which case I don't want to specify the installation directory, a compile mode, etc.) the first three parameters would gobble my arguments.  So, I would like to pass:

```
c:\> MyScript file-1.cs file-2.cs file-3.cs file-4.cs
```

and get all 4 strings appear $args, or alternatively, call:

```
c:\> MyScript -CompileMode simple file-1.cs -InstallDir c:\temp file-2.cs
```

and get values for $compilemode and $installdir with $args containing 2 files... how can I do that?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/11/named-arguments-for-powershell-functions-best-practices.aspx

Comment: Will the position of each parameter be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure I care whether the parameters I declare are fixed in position since the caller will have to name them (which is what I'm hoping for)

Comment: The article I linked above appears to cover this ground pretty well.

Comment: I read it.  it doesn't address my issue at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, figured it out.  declare like this:

```
param(
   $installdir, 
   $compilemode, 
   $whatever, 
   [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
   )
```

thanks to @latkin, who had already answered this at: [Powershell non-positional, optional params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375919/powershell-non-positional-optional-params)

Comment: `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) and shouldn't be hijacked like that.