# Argument list and the pipeline

Tags: powershell, parameters

as an adjunct to this issue: [How do I force declared parameters to require explicit naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861701/how-do-i-force-declared-parameters-to-require-explicit-naming) I am struggling with pipelines.  Suppose I want the behaviour that this declares:

```
param(
   $installdir, 
   $compilemode, 
   [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $files
   )
```

namely, that I can call my script like this:

```
c:\> MyScript -installdir c:\ file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt
```

but now I want to also be able to do it this way:

```
c:\> gi file-*.txt |MyScript -installdir c:\
```

I might think of adding a decoration to the parameter like this:

```
param(
   $installdir, 
   $compilemode, 
   [Parameter(
       Position=0, 
       ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true, 
       ValueFromPipeline=$true
   )] $files
   )
```

but what actually happens is I only get 1 argument into my parameter i.e. instead of getting an array with all the files that `gi` produced, I get only the first in the list.

A second way I attempted this was by using the `$input` variable (instead of using the `ValueFromPipeline` decorator), but then in trying to call the script I get the error:

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command 
>   either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input
>   and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
>   pipeline  input.

where can I go from here?

Answer (score 3):

You could declare it without ValueFromRemainingArguments:

```
param(
   [Parameter(
       Position=0, 
       ValueFromPipeline=$true,
       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
   [Alias('PSPath')]
   [string[]]
   $files,
   $installdir, 
   $compilemode
   )
```

And then pass in multiple files as an array using the comma operator e.g.:

```
 MyScript -installdir c:\ file-1.txt,file-2.txt,file-3.txt
```

Note: In order to accept input from commands like Get-Item and Get-ChildItem, use ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName and add a parameter alias "PSPath" that will find the PSPath property on the objects output by Get-Item/Get-ChildItem.

I have test this in ISE and it works fine:

```
function foo
{
    param(
       [Parameter(
           Position=0, 
           ValueFromPipeline=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
       [Alias('PSPath')]
       [string[]]
       $files,
       $installdir, 
       $compilemode
       )

    process {
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            "File is $file, installdir: $installdir, compilemode: $compilemode"
        }
    }
}

foo a,b,c -installdir c:\temp -compilemode x64
ls $home -file | foo -installdir c:\bin -compilemode x86
```

FYI, this is a template I use all the time to create commands that take pipeline input or array input, as well as wildcard paths:

```
function Verb-PathLiteralPath
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path",
                   SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    #[OutputType([output_type_here])] # Uncomment this line and specify the output type  of this
                                      # function to enable Intellisense for its output.
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   Position=0, 
                   ParameterSetName="Path", 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Path to one or more locations.")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [Alias("PSPath")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   Position=0, 
                   ParameterSetName="LiteralPath", 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Literal path to one or more locations.")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $LiteralPath
    )

    Begin 
    { 
        Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    }

    Process 
    {
        if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Path")
        {
            if (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
                $ex = new-object System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException "Cannot find path '$Path' because it does not exist."
                $category = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ObjectNotFound
                $errRecord = new-object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $ex, "PathNotFound", $category, $Path
                $psCmdlet.WriteError($errRecord)
            }

            # In the -Path (non-literal) case, resolve any wildcards in path
            $resolvedPaths = $Path | Resolve-Path | Convert-Path
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!(Test-Path $LiteralPath)) {
                $ex = new-object System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException "Cannot find path '$LiteralPath' because it does not exist."
                $category = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ObjectNotFound
                $errRecord = new-object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord $ex, "PathNotFound", $category, $LiteralPath
                $psCmdlet.WriteError($errRecord)
            }

            # Must be -LiteralPath
            $resolvedPaths = $LiteralPath | Convert-Path
        }

        foreach ($rpath in $resolvedPaths) 
        {
            if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($rpath, "Operation"))
            {
                # .. process rpath
            }
        }  
    }

    End
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah.  I may have to do that.  I don't like it because instinct says you separate lists with spaces.  alternatively, perhaps I could run through the $args variable, but it still leaves me with the issue of having to declare at least one parameter with a position so that the others are required by name.  sigh... perl is so much better at this

Comment: I guess what's really bothering me here is that there seems to be a confusion between arguments and the pipeline object.  things piped into my script are not arguments yet, my param() declaration fails when I try piping stuff in and I don't understand why... and specifically it complains when I declare a parameter with a Position=0

Comment: in any case, your solution does not work because so long as I declare a parameter with a Position value, I can't seem to pipe anything into the script (and I don't understand why)

Comment: The advantage of taking an array of files is that is what most PowerShell users would expect at this point.  It also means you can use the same parameter for pipeline binding. Not sure why you're getting an error with the Position property.  Works for me.  :-)

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention: I'm running Powershell 3.0