# PowerShell script not assigning named parameter correctly

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a script that starts with the following block

```
Param(
    [string] $c,

    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    [string] $args
)
```

When I call this script and specify `-n -cc -ou name -c 16.0.`, it seems like it just takes the whole command line and stuffs it into `$c`. If I do it with

```
[Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
[string] $args
```

then it does not actually pick up `-c 16.0.` and put it into `$c` at all, but just stuffs everything into `$args`. Why?

So what I want is hopefully simple. `-c` can be specified, but doesn't have to. There can also be a bunch of other params that can be specified, but don't have to and for those I just want to collect them in one string. If `-c` is specified, I want it to be put into `$c`, but left out of `$args`. if `-c` is not specified, `$c` variable should be empty. How to achieve that?

This is the answer I tried using and it doesn't work for me:

[How do I force declared parameters to require explicit naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861701/how-do-i-force-declared-parameters-to-require-explicit-naming)

Comment: @darxsys How are you actually invoking the script? Please show the exact command you're running.

Comment: While it may be old, I agree completely with @mklement0 that this should be re-opened (and I've voted as such). It also just helped me prevent what would have been a larger issue later in what I'm working on, had I not seen this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While **it is generally ill-advised to name a parameter `$args`**, as Ansgar Wiechers points out, because `$args` is normally an [*automatic* variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), your solution should still work in *principle*, at least in recent PowerShell versions.

However, as TessellatingHeckler points out, invocation with `-ou` causes an error, because - due to use of a parameter attribute (`[Parameter(...)]`) - your function is an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) that implicitly supports [*common parameters* such as `-OutVariable` and `-OutBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters), which `-ou` tries to bind to based on name-*prefix* matching, but fails due to *ambiguity*.
The bigger issue, however, is that you therefore **cannot pass (non-declared) parameter names that are prefixes of common parameter names in *advanced functions* as-is**.

(Another side effect of using an advanced function is that the automatic `$Args` variable is *not* populated, because you can only pass arguments that bind to *declared* parameters to an *advanced* function.)

***Suboptimal* workaround**:

- **Place all all pass-through arguments at the *end* of the command line** and **precede them `--`**, the special parameter that indicates that all remaining tokens are to be interpreted as *positional* arguments, even if they look like parameter names.

```
# Everything after -- (which itself will be removed), is passed
# through as a *positional* argument (which a ValueFromRemainingArguments
# parameter would collect).
Foo -c 16.0 -- -n -cc -ou name
```

Note: You could alternatively *quote* individual tokens to prevent their interpretation as a parameter name (e.g., `Foo -n -cc '-ou' name -c 16.0`), but that would require you to remember the names of all common parameters and apply quoting as needed.

---

**If the features of an *advanced* function aren't strictly needed, a better workaround is to use a *simple* function**:

- Use the *automatic* `$Args` variable for accessing all arguments not bound to declared parameters (do *not* declare it as a parameter).
- However, this requires that you neither use any parameter attributes nor the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, to prevent the function from becoming an *advanced* one - see [`about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced).

```
function Foo {
  # Don't use [CmdletBinding()] or [Parameter(...)] attributes.
  # Only then will the automatic $Args variable work.
  Param(
      [string] $c
  )

  "`$c: [$c]"

  # Use the automatic $Args variable, which collects all arguments
  # that did not bind to declared parameters in an array.
  $argsAsString = [string] $Args
  "`$Args: [$argsAsString]"
}

Foo -n -cc -ou name -c 16.0
```

The above yields:

```
$c: [16.0]
$args: [-n -cc -ou name]
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea about `--` that way, very interesting,